# Bad Company 2 - Any way to remove/disable C4?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-bad-company-2

The last few nights I've killed dudes at MCOMs after they've put the C4 on it.  When they die though, the C4 stays on the MCOM (this is stupid IMO - BF2 handled it much better). So someone else just throws a grenade in and the MCOM gets nearly 50% damage on it.  Is there a way to disable/remove it after killing someone who has placed it?

This also happened on a tank I was in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as of now, there is no way to disable C4. If you kill the guy who planted it, it will disappear eventually. I haven't found any details on exactly how long it persists, but I know from experience that C4 does disappear within a minute or two of the C4-planter's death.

So, if you can keep anyone from hitting the MCOM with explosives for a minute or so (maybe less), you've probably averted the danger the C4 presented.

Unfortunately for the defenders, none of this applies to AT Mines, which never disappear on their own, even after the Engineer who planted them is killed.

Comment: Bummer.  I liked it better when they died, the stuff they placed went away almost immediately. C'est la vie.

Comment: C4 will disappear when the player respawns.